# What methods can be used to interpolate values of a gradient?

Tags: computational-physics, simulations

Let's say I have a cubic mesh, the points of which I have obtained a vector value for, thus forming this discrete vector space of sort, I'm not really sure of the proper terminology for this which might be part of the problem.

Anyway, I want to interpolate the value of a vector inside of one of these cubes at a specific point. What are the names of some standard methods used to achieve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricubic_interpolation

Comment: How sharp is the gradient? Is it nearly discontinuous? Or is it rather smooth?

Comment: @tpg2114 I would say the latter, would be surprised if there are any discontinuities in more than finitely many points.

Comment: @KyleKanos I can see how this applies to point values, but what about when we have a vector and not a scalar? The only way I see is by interpolating x, y, z separately.